# Guidelines for Sharing code between Silverlight and WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I want to share as much code as possible between Silverlight and WPF.

- My lowest level handles the difference between calling the database directly and calling a web service.
- My data layer on top of that is compiled with both .NET and Silverlight.
- My GUI layer is currently designed as a WPF Control Library.

For sivlerlight...

1. Is it possible to reuse my XAML for my silverlight class library?
2. Do I need to create a "Silverlight Application" or can I just display controls from my class library directly?
3. What things do I need to be careful about? (For example, I already learned that Silverlight can't use DataTables in web service calls.)

Comment: I believe Silverlight uses it's own CLR, so I couldn't even share the dao dll between WPF and Silverlight.

Comment: My data and business layers share the same source files, but I have two project files, one for .NET and one for Silverlight.